# Having trouble with PDO Prepared Statement and "LIKE"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, first off, I know there are certain rules you have to follow when preparing a `LIKE` statement with PDO. I have already looked these up and I'm trying my best to follow them, but the query consistently returns no results even though I know the query itself is legitimate (MySQL command line client works correctly with the query).

This is for a school project; I need to make a website with a MySQL/php backend for a fictional bookstore.

I have a class in a php script called `DBConnection`. It is in a separate namespace (hence the backslashes for PDO objects and functions). This is part of it:

```
<?php
    class DBConnection {
        // ...

       public function prepAndExecute($sql, $args) {
           try {
               $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

               for($i = 1; $i <= count($args); $i++) {
                   $stmt->bindValue($i, $args[$i-1], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
               }

               $stmt->execute();

               return $stmt;
            } catch(\PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The actual MySQL query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM Book WHERE Title LIKE "%rich%";
```

My attempt at using a PDO Prepared Statement to run this on the website:

```
<?php
    // based on the search form from the previous page
    // (all values are set correctly by the form, already tested)
    $criteria = $_POST["searchCriteria"]; // "Title" (from a <select> element)
    $term = $_POST["searchTerm"]; // "rich" (from the text box)

    $conn = new DBConnection(); // uses namespace correctly, just didn't
                                // include here for simplicity
    $sql = "SELECT ISBN, Title, Author, Price FROM Book WHERE ? LIKE ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepAndExecute($sql, array($criteria, "%" . $term . "%"));
    // I have also tried $term = "%" . $term . "%", still no luck

    echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 0
?>
```

I ran the above query in the MySQL command line, and got 1 result as expected. I know the class/functions work because I use that same function to run all other SELECT and INSERT queries, and have had no problems until I try to run this LIKE statement.

Am I doing something wrong? Because I double and triple checked everything and could have sworn I was doing this right.

Comment: I believe you can't use `$criteria`/`?`'s for column names

Comment: Thank you @Class - I just stuck the variable in for the column name and it works.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` LIKE :keyword');
// Put the percentage sing on the keyword
$keyword = "%".$keyword."%";
// Bind the parameter
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem was that I was using a ? for the column name which it doesn't like.